# AJAX make Array Global

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, global

I'm trying to store corresponding data values from a XML returning AJAX into global array and then letter call function that will remove some elements from it but have problem to do it.
Array is not global.
Here is the bad code. 
Thanks for help.

```
var someArray=new Array();
function refreshPage() {
    downloadUrl("page.php", function(data) {
        markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
            var value=markers[i].getAttribute("Value");
            someArray.push(value);
        }
    });
    window.setTimeout("refreshPage()",5000);
}

function removeElement(value){
    someArray.slice(value,1);
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var status = -1;
    var request = createXmlHttpRequest();
    if (!request) {
       return false;
    }
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        try {
          status = request.status;
        } catch (e) {
    }
    if (status == 200) {
       callback(request.responseXML, request.status);
       request.onreadystatechange = function() {};
    }
  }
}
request.open('GET', url, true);
  try {
    request.send(null);
  } catch (e) {
    changeStatus(e);
  }
};
```

Comment: First of all change "downloadUrl("page.php, function(data) {"
to "downloadUrl("page.php", function(data) {"

Comment: did you mean to use `removeElement()` in your `setTimeout` instead?

Comment: `slice` grabs a subset of an Array. It does not delete things. The scope does not appear to be the problem.

Comment: Looks pretty global to me, but you're not changing the array ?

Comment: Are you sure markers has data? `console.log(markers)` just after you defined it and `console.log(value)` just after you define it. Are you seeing what you expect? sample XML might be helpful too.

Comment: missed one " near page.php

Comment: No. **Do not use** a global array here. Btw, where are you calling `refreshPage()` (for the first time), and where are you accessing the `someArray`?

Comment: function refreshes every 5 seconds and populates array here is xml echo '<marker
  Value="'.$Value.'"/>';  but that is fine. Once i try to alert array outside this function or remove element from it doesnt work. maybe slice is a problem

Comment: <body onLoad="refreshPage()"> from this page i call removeElement

Comment: Please show us the code that alerts the array and calls `removeElement` - probably it is executed at the wrong time. Btw, `slice` might indeed be a problem, did you want to use `splice`?

Comment: inside refresh page i have function that does $('#someid').html('<a href=some.php?'+someArray+'); i cant even alert array inside this function but html code is inserted to the page with div with id  someid no problem and array apears. and i use array data to polulate table in some dialog and from there i call function removeElement. Splice is a way to go

Answer (score 0):

have you thought about using local storage?

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");

// Retrieve
localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

If you want to stay with ajax do something like this

```
var it_works = false;

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  url: "some_file.php",
  data: "",
  success: function() {it_works = true;}
});

alert(it_works);
```